# Are there reasonable exemptions for eslint promise/no-nesting rule?

Tags: eslint

An eslint `promise/no-nesting` rule violation will occur for the following example:

```
  return foo()
    .catch(handleErrorAndReject('foo'))
    .then(() => bar().catch(handleErrorAndReject('bar')))
    .then(() => baz().catch(handleErrorAndReject('baz')))
```

Note that handleErrorAndReject is a curried function like this:

```
const handleErrorAndReject = action => error => {
   console.warn(`${action} fails with error`, error)
   res.status(400).send(error.message).end()
   return Promise.reject(error)
}
```

But the nested catches seem necessary in this case, because they vary by stage. Is this a case where I should just `eslint-disable`, or is there a better way to structure this code?